# Insert attachment via Apex failed

Tags: apex, attachment

When trying to insert new attachments, sometimes I come across this error:

```
Insert failed. First exception on row 1; first error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, BlobField : U#360.3fffffff (Attachment) U#360.aff (Body) got exception lib.http.storage.HttpFileStore$FileStoreActionException: Unable to complete action on FileStore in allotted time (timeout=600000 msec, took 10009 msecs)
```

This seems like a rare error since I haven't been able to find others who have met this issue.

Function to create attachment:

```
public static Attachment getAttachment(String body, String filename) {
    Attachment att = new Attachment();
    att.Body = Blob.valueOf(body);
    att.Name = fileName;
    return att;
}
```

Call the function:

```
Attachment att = getAttachment(JSON.serialize(testBody), 'Test.txt');
insert att;
```

where testBody is an instance of Map

Comment: Can you post your code or some more information?

Comment: @Arabinda yes I've edited the code in

Comment: Are you getting this error consistently? Is it on a single org? How big is testBody variable?

Comment: @rael_kid it is on a single org. It happened only in one period but there were about 75 error logs. testBody varies. Sometimes it's just a normal JSON array (3 or 4 arrays, less than a MB in file size) and sometimes it can be a pdf file of 100 rows.

Comment: If it was just during a single period it may be related to a Salesforce performance issue.

Comment: You didn't set ParentId on Attachment, its required field.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to detect this specific error condition and then handle the timeout in the way that makes sense for your business logic.

You could check for the string "Unable to complete action on FileStore in allotted time" and then retry the operation using a simple max retry count or exponential backoff algorithm.